# Post request return 404 in laravel

Tags: laravel

I write two api. One get function and one post function.

Also, I try

```
public function one(Request $request){
dd("test"); }

public function two(){
dd("test");
}
```

Always two is working but one does not working. I use http://127.0.0.1:8000.

And my api.php like

```
Route::post('/one', [\App\Http\Controllers\TestController::class, 'one']);
Route::get('/two', [\App\Http\Controllers\TestController::class, 'two']);
```

One always return 404 not found. How can I access this service?

Comment: Function `two()` seems to be missing a closing `"` and a terminating `;` ?

Comment: Problem is one. I did not copy paste. Just a write. As you said two is dd("test");

Comment: `one()` is using `POST` request, are you sure you make a `POST` request instead of `GET`?

Comment: have you checked any routes conflicting with 'one' ?

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the cache of routes.

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

the code looks correct.

Could you please let me know your web server (e.g. Apache/Nginx)?
Have you activated the rewrite module?

Alternatively, if you are using Laravel and starting the server with `php artisan serve`, you should restart it after editing or changing the code.

or like @fuadps said "are you sure you are access /one by POST request?"

Comment: Yes it is a post request. I try to send request with postman. I use localhost with xampp

Comment: and do you check your mod_rewrite is enabled?